# why is this weierstrass equation irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I was reading Silverman's Arithmetic of elliptic curves, chapter 3, proposition 3.1, which says that via Riemann Roch one can find functions $x,y$ on an elliptic curve which satisfy a weierstrass equation. One obtains a morphism $\psi : E \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ given by $[x:y:1]$ whose image lies in the zero locus $C$ of this Weierstrass equation. Then Silverman **claims this morphism is surjective,** the reason being that $C$ is irreducible and the map is non constant.

My question is, why is said locus irreducible?

Comment: A smooth plane curve is always irreducible (any two components intersect  by Bezout, and the points of intersections are automatically singularities). The possible singularities are listed in Proposition 1.4. Proposition 2.5 (among other things) implies that the zero locus is irreducible even in the singular cases. There are other routes to the same conclusion, some probably simpler.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you

Answer (score 1):

JyrkiLahtonen's comment answered my question, so im posting it here:

A smooth plane curve is always irreducible (any two components intersect by Bezout, and the points of intersections are automatically singularities). The possible singularities are listed in Proposition 1.4. Proposition 2.5 (among other things) implies that the zero locus is irreducible even in the singular cases. There are other routes to the same conclusion, some probably simpler.

Comment: Some friendly advice: when posting an answer after a question was answered in the comments, it's best practice to copy the comment(s) that resolved the question in to the answer - comments can be removed much more easily than answers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2018525)

Comment: @Ricky It did answer the question for me though

Comment: @KReiser just added it, thanks for the comment